# Python -- Using turtle graphics with nested lists. How do I solve this?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists, turtle-graphics

I have a nested list like this:

```
data_set_07 = [['A', 1, 3, 'S'], ['A', 2, 3, 'S'], ['A', 3, 1, 'S'],
               ['A', 3, 0, 'S'], ['A', 5, 2, 'S'], ['A', 5, 3, 'S'],
               ['B', 0, 0, 'S'], ['B', 0, 2, 'S'],
               ['C', 3, 2, 'S'], ['C', 4, 0, 'S'],
               ['D', 1, 0, 'S']]
```

`'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'` and `'D'` are all references to dimensions (1x1, 1x2, 2x2, etc.).
The numbers are in reference to a specific column and row on a graph and the `'S'` stands for 'SOUTH' (as in, the icon should face south).

I have drawn 4 different icons using the turtle graphics on python and I need each icon to be drawn on the graph in these different settings (some smaller than others, and in different locations but all specific to the numbers above in the lists.)

What I need to know is, what do I do to my code to add `data_set_07` so it puts my icons on the graph in the correct positions and not just in the default position?

**One of my icons to be used with `data_set_07`:**

```
def NBC(data_set):
    pu()
    color('yellow')
    begin_fill()
    setheading(183)
    pd()
    fd(150)

    circle(-40, 190)
    right(19)
    fd(165)
    end_fill()
    pu()
    left(5)
    fd(5)

    left(173)
    pd()
    color('orange')
    begin_fill()
    pd()
    fd(150)

    circle(-40, 190)
    right(19)
    fd(165)
    end_fill()
    pu()
    left(5)

    left(173)
    pd()
    color('red')
    begin_fill()
    pd()
    fd(150)

    circle(-40, 190)
    right(19)
    fd(165)
    end_fill()
    pu()
    setheading(90)
    right(170)

    left(168)
    pd()
    color('purple')
    begin_fill()
    pd()
    fd(150)

    circle(-40, 190)
    right(19)
    fd(165)
    end_fill()
    pu()

    left(179)
    pd()
    color('blue')
    begin_fill()
    pd()
    fd(150)

    circle(-40, 190)
    right(19)
    fd(165)
    end_fill()
    pu()

    left(180)
    pd()
    color('green')
    begin_fill()
    pd()
    fd(150)

    circle(-40, 190)
    right(19)
    fd(165)
    end_fill()
    pu()


NBC(data_set_07)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your icon will always be drawn the same size.  If you want to be able to vary the size according to the dimensions, as I take it, you'll have to parametrize your icon functions.  Something like

```
def NBC(height, width, x, y)
```

Then you'll have to add code to move to (x, y) to begin with.  I haven't looked at turtle graphics in many years, so I can't say what the exact command for this is.  After that, you have to scale your movements by height and width.  (Height and width could be multiples of the default size, so that that height=1, width=1 means draw it in the default size, and height=1, width=2 means draw it with the default height but make the width twice as large.)

If you really want to change the aspect ratio like this, you may not like the result.  You'll also have to change the headings.  It just takes a little trigonometry to figure out what the angle should be.  If the original heading is theta, then the new heading would be

`arctan(width*tan(theta)/height)`

if I haven't made a mistake.  You could also make the logo face in different directions by passing the direction as a parameter.  If the default direction is 'E' then you can just define a dict, say

`angle = {'E':0, 'N':90, 'W':180, 'S':270}`

pass the desired direction as a parameter phi, and add angle[phi] to all the headings.

May I suggest that you not try to get this all working at once.  Start by just moving the logo to different positions.  Then work on scaling where the aspect ratio doesn't change (width = height).  Then work on changing the orientation.  Finally try changing the aspect ratio if you really want to.